# Push None or empty values to last of json array in datetime sorted lambda function

Tags: python, arrays, json, sorting

I am building a simple function But I am stuck on an error, I am trying to `sort json array` based on `datetime` defined it the response. But `JSON array` also contains some `None` and `Empty string` dates like `""`. so It is showing

> KeyError: 'date'
> when it sees `None` or `empty date value`

so I am trying to push these type of value in the last of the sorted json array which have None and empty string values (date).

```
example_response = [
    {
      "id": 2959,
      "original_language": "Permanent Job",
      "date": "2012-10-26",
      "absent": False
    },
    {
      "id": 8752,
      "original_language": "Intern Job",
      "date": "",
      "absent": True
    },
    {
      "adult": False,
      "id": 1300,
      "title": "Training Job",
      "date": "2020-07-25",
      "absent": False
    },
    {
      "adult": False,
      "id": 7807,
      "title": "Training Job",
      "absent": False
    },
]
```

program.py

```
def sorting_function(response):
    if response == True:
        sorted_data = sorted(example_response, key=lambda x: datetime.strptime(x['date'], "%Y-%m-%d"))
        print(sorted_data)

    return sorted_data
```

As you can see in `example_response` one `dict` has empty string and one don't have "date".
When I run this function then it is showing **KeyError: 'date'**

**What I have tried ?**

I have also tried using

```
sorted_data = sorted(example_response, key=lambda x: (x['date'] is None, x['date'] == "", x['date'], datetime.strptime(x['date']), "%Y-%m-%d"))
```

But it still showing `KeyError`.

Any help would be much Appreciated.

Comment: Where in the order would dictionaries with missing 'date' key go? If 'date' value is an empty string does that precede or succeed other dates? Also, if the dates are in the format shown in your example, there's no need to convert them to datetime objects as they can be compared lexicographically

Comment: It is preceding every other dates. Should I not user `datetime.strptime` to convert the dates ?

Comment: No need to convert them because dates in the form of YYYY-MM-DD can be ordered by lexical comparison. See my answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dictionaries have a very useful *get()* function which you could utilise thus:

```
example_response = [
    {
      "id": 2959,
      "original_language": "Permanent Job",
      "date": "2012-10-26",
      "absent": False
    },
    {
      "id": 8752,
      "original_language": "Intern Job",
      "date": "",
      "absent": True
    },
    {
      "adult": False,
      "id": 1300,
      "title": "Training Job",
      "date": "2020-07-25",
      "absent": False
    },
    {
      "adult": False,
      "id": 7807,
      "title": "Training Job",
      "absent": False
    }
]

example_response.sort(key=lambda d: d.get('date', ''))

print(example_response)
```

In this case, missing or empty 'date' values would precede any other dates.

**Output:**

```
[{'id': 8752, 'original_language': 'Intern Job', 'date': '', 'absent': True}, {'adult': False, 'id': 7807, 'title': 'Training Job', 'absent': False}, {'id': 2959, 'original_language': 'Permanent Job', 'date': '2012-10-26', 'absent': False}, {'adult': False, 'id': 1300, 'title': 'Training Job', 'date': '2020-07-25', 'absent': False}]
```

Comment: It worked But I used `reverse=True` to create the array in reverse order so It can adjusts `None` and `empty values` at the end of the array

Comment: But you commented that you want empty or missing dates to precede valid dates

Comment: But It was showing on top of the array so I think it is better. Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

### Don't call `strptime` if `x['date']` is `None`

If the key is

```py
lambda x: (x['date'] is None, datetime.strptime(x['date'], "%Y-%m-%d"))
```

Then the pair will be computed for all values, which means `strptime` will be called on all `x['date']`, including those that are `None`.

I suggest using a conditional, in order to only call `strptime` if `x['date']` is not `None`:

```py
lambda x: (0, datetime.strptime(x['date'], "%Y-%m-%d")) if x['date'] is not None else (1, 0)
```

### Use `x.get('date')` instead of `x['date']` if `x` might be missing the `'date'` key

If `x` is a dict that doesn't have a `'date'`, then attempting to access `x['date']` will always cause a `KeyError`, even for something as simple as `x['date'] is None`.

Instead, you can use `dict.get`, which doesn't cause errors. If a value is missing, `dict.get` will return `None`, or another value which you can provide as a second argument:

```py
x = { "id": 2959, "original_language": "Permanent Job" }

print(x['date'])
# KeyError

print(x.get('date'))
# None

print(x.get('date', 42))
# 42
```

Finally, the key function for the sort becomes:

```py
lambda x: (0, datetime.strptime(x.get('date'), "%Y-%m-%d")) if x.get('date') is not None else (1, 0)
```

Note that if the key function becomes too complex, it might be better to write it using `def` instead of `lambda`:

```py
def key(x):
    date = x.get('date')
    if date is None:
        return (1, 0)
    else:
        return (0, datetime.strptime(date, "%Y-%m-%d"))
```

Comment: If there is no 'date' key in any of the dictionaries, this will result in KeyError

Comment: Yes it is showing key error

Comment: @OldBill You commented too fast.

Comment: @Stef So it was my mistake. Fair enough

Answer (score 0):

You're nearly on the right track, but you need to find a way to not evaluate the date string when it is invalid (key not present, or the value is the empty string).

The nice thing about dates is that chronological order is the same as lexicographical order (for ISO-8601 date formats -- `%Y-%m-%d`). So you don't actually have to convert them to dates or datetimes -- just sort them as strings.

That takes care of items in the sequence which have date keys. But what about ones where the date key is not present? There are three options.

1. Use a a default value. eg. the empty string. However, this means no-date-items will be mixed together with empty-date-items.
2. Use a fixed-length tuple where the first item indicates whether the date key is present or not and then a default when the value is not present. eg `(False, '')`, `(True, '')` and `(True, '2022-10-03')`. These values will sort in the order I gave them.
3. Use a variable length tuple. Tuples with different lengths have a total ordering iff their shared elements are comparable. Much like strings do. eg. `car` sorts before `care`. So we can use `()` to represent a no-date-item, `('',)` to represent an empty-date-item and `('2022-10-3',)` to represent a normal date string.

Using the third possibility you can do:

```py
sorted(
    example_response,
    key=lambda item: (item['date'],) if 'date' in item else ()
)
```

This ensures items in the sequence with a date key are sorted separately to items where the value of date key is the empty string. However, both are sorted before all valid dates.

The keys and their sort order for your example would be:

```py
[(), ('',), ('2012-10-26',), ('2020-07-25',)]
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, I am getting this Data from API so there's no way to define custom field so I can know if date is present or not and valid or not